# Python 3.6 remove words that do not start with a vowel from a text file

Tags: python

I am learning Python 3.6. I would like to know how to remove a word that does not start with a vowel reading in from a text file. I have already a text file called `someStates.txt` so I don't have to read in from a path for now.

When I run the code I get `someState.txt not defined`. I want the output to create a text file with words that don't start with a vowel.

What am I doing wrong?

```
infile = open('someStates.txt', 'r')
infile.close()

vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','y','A','E','I','O','u','Y') 

filteredStates.txt = [state
                    for state in someStates.txt
                      if state[0].rstrip().lower()
                        not in vowels] 
infile = open('filteredStates.txt','w')
infile.close()
print( 'infile')
```

Comment: Variable names can't have a `.` in them. Just use `filteredStates`.

Comment: Don't close the `infile` file object before you are done reading from it. `someStates.txt` is not the variable name of the open file object, it's just the filename. You want to use `infile` instead of `someStates.txt`, and close the file **after** looping.

Comment: why is `Y` in vowels?  Also `u` is put in lower case twice

Answer (score 1):

''' 
Im new to this, listening to many of the advice here this is what I got

'''

```
#input

infile = open('someStates.txt', 'r') # read in a text file frome my directory

#process

filterState=[line.rstrip() for line in infile] 
infile.close() 

vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','y','A','E','I','O','U','Y')

filterState=[state for state in filterState
                      if state[0].rstrip().lower()
                      not in vowels]
infile.close()


#output


print(filterState)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('someStates.txt', 'r')
infile.close()


                    for state in someStates.txt
```

That is not how it works ;)

`open()` returns a file object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

From the file object, you can then [read](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) data into a string variable with `data = infile.read()`. (Do this before closing the file.)

Then you need to split the string into words with `words = data.split()`. Only after that you can loop over the words.